# Android action bar 'overlay'

Tags: android-actionbar, overlay

Im working on an android application that uses an action bar - which all works well.

One thing I would like to do is to display the 'underscore' of the icon that has been selected - I believe a kind of a graphic overlay so that the user knows what section they are in. This has been done in many apps but I'm not sure if its possible with the action bar .

This [image](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&docid=yHZsrvhtaFo17M&tbnid=jBinnXO6cNkp5M:&ved=0CAcQjRw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.techhive.com%2Farticle%2F2033037%2Ftwitter-overhauls-android-app.html&ei=11cqVPXRNMPdatSpgJAN&bvm=bv.76477589,d.d2s&psig=AFQjCNH3dcYTesRRRcf8hzMUlNhyj3Lfig&ust=1412147537768780) shows a bar under the home icon in use on the twitter app, can it be done?

Comment: I know its not good etiquette to answer your own posts, but I've just found that if I use a TAB bar i can do this! Lets hope the tab bar can use icons!<https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs>

Comment: Use tabactivity, u will get default the "underscore" which u have been selected or u can customize (or) Use ActionBar.Tab and use split

Answer (score 3):

Overlaying action bar provide great effect on layouts,
Use **android:windowActionBarOverlay**  for **name** keyword in **item** tag

```
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```